# After encrypt then encode, how to decrypt and decode properly with AES in small Java program

Tags: java, encoding, aes

I have a method to convert a **byte array** to a single **String**. It works also as expected. It looks like following:

**Main.java**

```
private static String HexToStr(byte[] allBytes) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : AllBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", (int) b & 0xFF));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But now I'm trying to write another method to do the opposite operation (strToHex) and decode the original encrypted and encoded text with same method specification as the above one, means:

```
private static String strToHex(byte[] allBytes) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
   // start here 
   ...
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        ... // here is where i'm missing something

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Later on, I test all with a small **"main"**-method as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String str = "Alpha Beta Gamma"; // text to encode and decode
    Secret myKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
    Cipher myCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    // encrypt then encode
    myCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    byte[] encryptResBytes = myCipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
    String encryptResBytesEncoded = HexToStr(encryptResBytes);
    System.out.println("decrypt or decode should be first ?: " + encryptResBytesEncoded);
    
    // Decode then decrypt or decrypt then decode ? 
    // I'm not sure any more, so be free to say how you think I could go ahead :)
    ...
    myCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey);
    byte[] decryptResBytes = myCipher.doFinal(encryptResBytesEncoded.getBytes());
    String decryptResBytesDecoded = StrToHex(decryptResBytes);
    System.out.println("Encrypt and encoded custom text: " + encryptResBytesEncoded);
    ...
    ...
    

}
```

How can I continue at this point?

Comment: It is not really HexToStr, it is rather ByteToStr. Your encoding is very bad on the size. Try to use Base64 or the real hex encoding. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html . Also, You use the AES without defining the encryption mode, as a result it chooses ECB with PKCS#5 (actually PKCS#7) padding. Don't use ECB, use at least CBC or CTR or better AES-GCM.

Comment: I've actually got a hex encoder based on the same principles / class structure as the base 64 codec which I always forget to file the appropriate bug report for (so including e.g. streaming).

Comment: @kelalaka, i know **Base64**  from Codec is the best way to go, but for a simple **URL** paramter or token, i will better go with **HEX** (0-f). But it,s not my issue right now, i,m just trying if with my short program right there, i will be able to recover my **plain-text** again.

Comment: HEX encoding is way costlier than the Base64.

Comment: Okay, because of the length i suppose ?